# The order of premises

Tags: isabelle

How to change the order of premises in a rule?
For instance, in Isabelle's natural deduction rule:

```
mp: ?P ⟶ ?Q ⟹ ?P ⟹ ?Q
```

Can we change the order to:

```
?P ⟹ ?P ⟶ ?Q ⟹ ?Q
```

I can use `rev_mp` or define a new lemma, but what I am looking for is whether there is a theorem modifier that changes the order of premises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The premises of a theorem can be rotated with the attribute `rotated`. You can also specify the number of premises to rotate, e.g., `mp[rotated 1]`. AFAIK there's no attribute for arbitrarily permuting the premises.